# How do i make all elements in my div tag responsible when changing the size (zooming in / out)

Tags: html, css, header

I have the topnav bar in the middle and when zooming out it stays there, but the picture(logo) and the tickets thing don't. Like you can see everythings is position relative. Also tried with margin auto, margin-left and margin-right auto but it just doesnt stay there. Also tried making the div just in the middle but that didn't work either. Every help is appreciated. :)

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
}


#header{
    background-color: #a61b2b;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
    height: 120px;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: flex-end
}

#topnav li{
    margin: 0px 5px;
}

#topnav{
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
    right: 460px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans',arial,sans-serif;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
}

#topnav a:hover {
    background-color: #eb0627;
}

#topnav a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #fff
}

#topnav li:hover ul{
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    background: black;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}

#topnav li ul li{
    margin: 10px 0px;
}

#logo{
    position: relative;
    left: 500px;
    width: 55%;
}

#tickets{
    position: relative;
    left: 450px;
    background-color: black;
}


.hidden{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Granada Club de Fútbol | Granada </title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <img alt="Logo" id="logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/gTqYynf/logo.png">
    <ul id="topnav">
        <li><a href="#">NEWS</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">CLUB</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">FIRST TEAM</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">THE CLUB</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">CLUB INFORMATION</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">STRUCTURE</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">FIRST TEAM</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">SQUAD </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">TRAINING</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">TEAMS</a>
            <ul class="hidden">
                <li><a href="#">GRANADA B </a></li>
                <li><a href="#">GFC LADIES</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">GRANADA TV</a>
        </li>
        <li><a id="tickets" href="#">TICKETS</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For everyone having a similiar problem, i found a solution. just make a second div tag under the header tag which has a fixed with and margin left and right auto. this makes a div tag in the middle which won't move.

Here's the code of how i fixed it.

```css
        body{
            margin: 0;
        }

        a{
            transition: all .25s;
        }

        #header{
            background-color: #a61b2b;
            display: flex;
            grid-template-columns: 20% 80%;
            height: 110px;
            align-content: center;
            justify-content: flex-end;
        }

        #h2{
            width: 975px;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            padding-top: 6px;
        }

        #topnav li{
            margin: 0px 5px;
        }

        #topnav{
            position: relative;
            font-family: 'Open Sans',arial,sans-serif;
            color: #f2f2f2;
            padding: 14px 16px;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            list-style: none;
            display: flex;
            margin: auto;
        }

        #topnav a:hover {
            background-color: #eb0627;
        }

        #topnav a{
            text-decoration:none;
            color: #fff
        }

        #topnav li:hover ul{
            display: block;
            list-style: none;
            background: black;
            color: #fff;
            padding: 10px;
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
        }

        #topnav li ul li{
            margin: 10px 0px;
        }

        #logo{
            position: relative;
            width: 20%;
        }

        #tickets{
            position: relative;
            left: 480px;
            background-color: #343434;
            padding: 8px;
        }

        #search{
            position: relative;
            top: -30px;
            left: 650px;
            width: 20px;
        }

        #fb{
            padding-right: 5px;
            width: 10px;
        }

        .hidden{
            display:none;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Granada Club de Fútbol | Granada </title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="h2">
        <img alt="Logo" id="logo" src="https://i.ibb.co/gTqYynf/logo.png">
        <img id="search" src="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/629756354701295616/707198877857480744/search-icon.png">
        <ul id="topnav">
            <li><a href="#">NEWS</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">CLUB</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">FIRST TEAM</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">THE CLUB</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">CLUB INFORMATION</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">STRUCTURE</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">FIRST TEAM</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">SQUAD </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TRAINING</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">TEAMS</a>
                <ul class="hidden">
                    <li><a href="#">GRANADA B </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">GFC LADIES</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">GRANADA TV</a>
            </li>
            <li><a id="tickets" href="#"><img id="fb" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/27/27212.svg">TICKETS</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```